# Count Consecutive Records matching a criteria in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-models

I have a rails model called UserAttempt which has `done_correct:boolean` entry in database.
The model has a method on it called `delta_tts` which returns a float value. ie., `user_attempt.delta_tts = some_float_value.`

Now i want to count the consecutive entries of UserAttempts in database which are having `done_correct = true and delta_tts > 5`.

Please give me possible approaches to this problem.

i need consecutive entries, lets suppose the entries in database are like this -

```
1. done_correct = true, delta_tts = 5.3 
2. done_correct = true, delta_tts = 6.3 
3. done_correct = false, delta_tts = 4.5 
4. done_correct = true, delta_tts = 5.6 
5. done_correct = true, delta_tts = 6.8 
6. done_correct = true, delta_tts = 5.8
```

I want the count to return 3. because there are only three recent consecutive entries matching the criteria.

Comment: According to your problem, shouldn't the value of count be 5

Comment: @AdityaKapoor I want the consecutive entries matching the criteria, 5 entries match the criteria as you see but only 3 in them are consecutive.(the last three entries)